# How to override HTML5 validation pop up?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a a `HTML` form. I have added `required` tag against each input fields for which I require it to be filled. I am using `$<form-name>.<input.field.name>.$error` in [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) to check for errors during submission and apply error class to those fields.

Is there a way to prevent `HTML5` validation popup retaining the `required` attribute at the same time?

Comment: Did you set the attribute `novalidate` to your form?

Comment: novalidate with required doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Why do you need a required field if the javaScript is doing the validation for you?

Comment: @Chris AngularJS is doing the validation and does that on fields with the attribute `required`.

Comment: @cezar I didn't know that "required" was required for AngularJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `novalidate` attribute.

```
<form novalidate>
    ...
</form>
```

[Form's `novalidate` attribute on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-novalidate)

Answer (score 2):

You can show your error message inside **dirty** condition of angular js and not on submission. Try like this:

```html
<span style="color:red" ng-show="$<form-name>.<input.field.name>.$dirty && $<form-name>.<input.field.name>.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="$<form-name>.<input.field.name>.$error.required">Name is required.</span>
</span>
```

This will show error message on focus out only. And on submit, default HTML5 required field error message will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `novalidate` at your form element:

```
<form novalidate>
    <input type="text" required>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```